# Best way to use Rspec Expect instead of should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have noticed that I am getting depreciation warnings using should instead of expect with rspec. I cant find the best way to implement expect for the following test

```
it "is invalid without a goal" do 
  FactoryGirl.build(:project, goal: nil).should_not be_valid 
end
```

If any help me out or put me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [documentation](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations) you could use `expect.to` something as follows:

```
it "is invalid without a goal" do 
   expect( FactoryGirl.build(:project, goal: nil) ).to_not be_valid 
end
```